# Breaking a foreach loop

Tags: php, web-scraping

I was unable to break out of a foreach loop. I think the structure is correct there is something else wrong with the code. Please let me know what is the issue,(not just a working code) i want to learn from my mistakes. Thanks

I am using simple html dom for scraping some piece of information and i want the loop to break when a condition is matched. Here is my code :

```
<?php
$mainjob = file_get_html('link to scrap here');
$newarr = array();
foreach($mainjob->find('td[valign=middle]') as $d) {
    $data = $d->innertext;
    $newarr[] = $data;
    echo $data . "<br>";
    if($data == "Job Opportunity Description:") {
        break;
    }

}
print_r($newarr);
```

Comment: What are the output of echo $data

Comment: Its the scrapped data which is in the output

Comment: if $data will not equal to the specific string than it wouldn't break this loop.

Comment: Often times, the source code has a lot of whitespace within a tag (which is stripped in the browser's output). Anyways, my point is it might be worth trying to trim the `innertext`. Like: `trim($data.trim) == ...`

Answer (score 0):

1) I guess your $data=="Job Opportunity Description:" condition wasn't true, so it didn't call the break;

2) Put your $mainjob->find('td[valign=middle]') out of your loop conditions, so it doesn't get called each iteration:

```
$tds = $mainjob->find('td[valign=middle]');
foreach($td as $d){}
```

3) Why did you add brackets to your $newarr variable?

4) Maybe your $data string still contains the html tags (which aren't shown by echo due to your browser.. so the condition would return false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the white space i used trim() to trim out the white space and it works. I recommend the answer from Ayman Safadi. Thanks.